# c++ confusion matrix error

Tags: c++, opencv, confusion-matrix, dlib

I'm trying to build a confusion matrix from a set of SVM prediction based on the OpenCV SVM train and predict function as so:

```
void testClassifier(CvSVM & SVM, 
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> & test_samples,
    std::vector<float> & test_labels,
    const CvSVMParams & params,
    double & tempAcc)
{
    cv::Mat matSamp;
    int response;
    int cnt = 0;
    //std::vector<int> labels = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    std::vector<int> exCount = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> confMat = { { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 } };


    //test classifier
    for (unsigned int t = 0; t < test_samples.size(); t++)
    {
        matSamp = cv::Mat(test_samples[t].size(), 1, CV_32FC1, test_samples[t].data());
        response = SVM.predict(matSamp);

        if (response == test_labels[t])
        {
            cnt++;
        }

        exCount[test_labels[t]] += 1;
        //cout << test_labels[t] << " " << exCount[test_labels[t]] << endl;
        confMat[test_labels[t]][response] += 1.0;
        //cout << confMat[test_labels[t]][response] << endl;
    }

    cout << "Parameters used: " << endl;
    tempAcc = (double)cnt * 100 / test_samples.size();
    cout << "  C:               " << params.C << endl;
    cout << "  Gamma:           " << params.gamma << endl;
    cout << "you hit " << tempAcc << "% accuracy" << endl << endl;
    cout << confMat[0][0] / exCount[0] * 100 << " " << confMat[0][1] / exCount[1] * 100 << " " << confMat[0][2] / exCount[2] * 100 << " " << confMat[0][3] / exCount[3] * 100 << " " << confMat[0][4] / exCount[4] * 100 << " " << confMat[0][5] / exCount[5] * 100 << " " << confMat[0][6] / exCount[6] * 100 << endl;
    cout << confMat[1][0] / exCount[0] * 100 << " " << confMat[1][1] / exCount[1] * 100 << " " << confMat[1][2] / exCount[2] * 100 << " " << confMat[1][3] / exCount[3] * 100 << " " << confMat[1][4] / exCount[4] * 100 << " " << confMat[1][5] / exCount[5] * 100 << " " << confMat[1][6] / exCount[6] * 100 << endl;
    cout << confMat[2][0] / exCount[0] * 100 << " " << confMat[2][1] / exCount[1] * 100 << " " << confMat[2][2] / exCount[2] * 100 << " " << confMat[2][3] / exCount[3] * 100 << " " << confMat[2][4] / exCount[4] * 100 << " " << confMat[2][5] / exCount[5] * 100 << " " << confMat[2][6] / exCount[6] * 100 << endl;
    cout << confMat[3][0] / exCount[0] * 100 << " " << confMat[3][1] / exCount[1] * 100 << " " << confMat[3][2] / exCount[2] * 100 << " " << confMat[3][3] / exCount[3] * 100 << " " << confMat[3][4] / exCount[4] * 100 << " " << confMat[3][5] / exCount[5] * 100 << " " << confMat[3][6] / exCount[6] * 100 << endl;
    cout << confMat[4][0] / exCount[0] * 100 << " " << confMat[4][1] / exCount[1] * 100 << " " << confMat[4][2] / exCount[2] * 100 << " " << confMat[4][3] / exCount[3] * 100 << " " << confMat[4][4] / exCount[4] * 100 << " " << confMat[4][5] / exCount[5] * 100 << " " << confMat[4][6] / exCount[6] * 100 << endl;
    cout << confMat[5][0] / exCount[0] * 100 << " " << confMat[5][1] / exCount[1] * 100 << " " << confMat[5][2] / exCount[2] * 100 << " " << confMat[5][3] / exCount[3] * 100 << " " << confMat[5][4] / exCount[4] * 100 << " " << confMat[5][5] / exCount[5] * 100 << " " << confMat[5][6] / exCount[6] * 100 << endl;
    cout << confMat[6][0] / exCount[0] * 100 << " " << confMat[6][1] / exCount[1] * 100 << " " << confMat[6][2] / exCount[2] * 100 << " " << confMat[6][3] / exCount[3] * 100 << " " << confMat[6][4] / exCount[4] * 100 << " " << confMat[6][5] / exCount[5] * 100 << " " << confMat[6][6] / exCount[6] * 100 << endl;
    cout << "enter for next matrix" << endl;/**/
    cin.get();
}
```

but when the matrix entries are outputted some rows sum to greater than 100% and some less. I'm sure its something simple but I've been staring at it for ages with no clue. any ideas?

---

## UPDATE

Im not sure why but the multiple `cout` I was using affected the return value.

The problem was solved by including the debugging `cout` in a for loop like this:

```
for (unsigned int m = 0; m < 7; m++)
{
    for (unsigned int n = 0; n < 7; n++)
    {
        confMat[m][n] = confMat[m][n] * 100 / exCount[m];
        cout << confMat[m][n] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Anyone does know why?

Comment: didnt understand the code completely yet, but first thing I would try is to normalize `confMat[i][x]` with `exCount[i]`

Comment: this is what the final cout statements are about. i wanted to keep the matrix of predictions as a separate entity, confMat. also exCount is the total number of occurences of each type/label so isnt complete until outside of the loop, exCount[i] might not be the full total for normalizing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like I was right with my first guess. In the original you normalize like this:

```
confMat[i][m] / exCount[m] * 100
```

while in the correct code you normalize like this:

```
confMat[m][i] / exCount[m] * 100
```

Depending on whether `exCount` is counting the totals per row or per column you only get the correct answer with one of the above lines.

Comment: so by using confMat[1][2], as an example, i was actually accessing the 2nd element of the 3rd vector and not the other way around.. wouldn't confMat[1] be the 2nd vector though?

Comment: @rfho_bdss  well... I always (really always) confuse rows with columns, but as there are only two possibilities, it is rather easy to fix

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for next time, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure why but the multiple cout i was using affected the return value.

by including the debugging couts in a for loop like this:

```
for (unsigned int m = 0; m < 7; m++)
{
    for (unsigned int n = 0; n < 7; n++)
    {
        confMat[m][n] = confMat[m][n] * 100 / exCount[m];
        cout << confMat[m][n] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

sorted the issue. any know why?

Comment: Please delete this answer. I edited your question to contain this text.

Comment: Refresh your browser. See the section UPDATE in your question.

Comment: ahh i see! whats wrong with having my solution here though?

Comment: You solved it and asked a question afterwards. You would need to separate that.